# Set a default GPG key id for email

Tags: gnupg

If I have imported several keys (with different key ids that I can see when I `gpg --list-keys`) that all have the same email address, how do I set which one to encrypt to?

and ditto encrypt from/with, if I have created a few key IDs myself for my own email address.

I mean set it permamently, not just one time with `--recipient`.

I see a lot of documentation on the other way around, selecting or adding an email to a key ID. But here, there are a lot of keys for the same email instead of a lot of emails with the same key.

Comment: I later figured out an Emacs-specific solution, which is to edit `mml-secure-key-preferences`. Works for me ‍♀️

Comment: Talking to some people on irc://libera.chat/gnupg they suggested to revoke or expire the keys but warned me that could be dangerous so be careful. I didn't end up needing that since the Emacs solution worked for me but generally this seems to be a missing feature in gpg.